# Delete duplicate by using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete all record with condition

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a DataFrame
d = {
    'Name':['Alisa','Bobby','jodha','jack','raghu','Cathrine',
        'Alisa','Bobby','kumar','Alisa','Alex','Cathrine'],
        'Age':[26,24,23,22,23,24,26,24,22,23,24,24],
        'Score':[85,63,55,74,31,77,85,63,42,62,89,77]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['Name','Age','Score'])
df
```

I want to remove all the record of "Alisa" which is duplicate as she is having Score = 85

I have tried below code, but it still displays "Alisa"

```
df1 = df[df['Score']==85]
df.drop_duplicates(['Name'])
```

Comment: 1) Are you mixing `df` and `df1`? 2) `drop_duplicates()` is not inplace. If you need to continue working with the dataframe do `df = df.drop_duplicates('Name')`

Comment: Hi, Good morning, my condition is if score = 85 and name column is having duplicate name (in above example = "Alisa"), then all alisa should be deleted

Comment: To combine my two previous comments, do: `df1 = df[df['Score']==85].drop_duplicates(['Name'] )`

Comment: Show an example of your desired output.

Comment: df1 = df[df['Score'] == 85].drop_duplicates(keep='last')
df.drop(df1.index, inplace=True)    - In this case All name with Alisa is deleted

Comment: df1 = df[df['Score'] == 63].drop_duplicates(keep='last')
df.drop(df1.index, inplace=True) - in this case all name bobby will be remove

Comment: df1 = df[df['Score'] == 77].drop_duplicates(keep='last')
df.drop(df1.index, inplace=True) - Cathrine will removed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to drop all duplicates where 'Score' is equal to 85 you can use the following solution:

```
df1 = df[df['Score'] == 85].drop_duplicates(keep='last')
df.drop(df1.index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi, it is working for alisa only, same code should work for other also, for example if is change for score 85 to score 77 is should delete ' Cathrine', if i change score to 63, it should delete 'Bobby'....

Comment: You wrote in your comments that condition is score = 85. Then you can use `df.drop_duplicates()`.

Comment: Hi, I have condition with score, let say i want to have code like delete all duplicate name with score of "77", I mean there is condition in score to delete duplicate name.

Comment: So you can make a function like `def func(score): df[df['Score'] == score]` and so on.